# How to pass DateTimeOffset values in ServiceStack

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

I've got the following message:

```cs
[Route("/devices/{DeviceId}/punches/{EmployeeId}/{DateTime}", "GET,POST")]
public class Punch
{
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateTime { get; set; }
    public string TimeZoneId { get; set; }
    public PunchKind Kind { get; set; }
}
```

I need to pass a full `DateTimeOffset` in the DateTime part...

The following works perfectly:

`http://localhost:54146/devices/1001/punches/666/2012-04-01`

But when I try to pass the full date time offset data it's failing with a HTTP 400 Error: Bad Request. I've tried the following so far with the same error (even URL encoding it didn't help):

`http://localhost:54146/devices/1001/punches/666/2012-04-01T20:59:00.0000000-03:00`
`http://localhost:54146/devices/1001/punches/666/2012-04-01 20:59:00.0000000-03:00`
`http://localhost:54146/devices/1001/punches/666/2012-04-0120:59:00.0000000-03:00`
`http://localhost:54146/devices/1001/punches/666/2012-04-01T20%3A59%3A00.0000000-03%3A00`

And other permutations all fail with the same error.

How can I pass a DateTimeOffset as part of the URL?

Comment: try encoding the datetime part. e.g. `2012-04-01T20%3A59%3A00.0000000-03%3A00`

Comment: I've done that already... I'll update the question to show that I've already tried that out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<,>,*,%,&,:` and `\` are, by default, disallowed by ASP.NET in URLs. In your case, the colon is the culprit (it doesn't matter if it's encoded or not). You can fix it by adding the following to your Web.config file:

```
<system.web>
...
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,\" />
...
</system.web>
```

References:

- [HttpRuntimeSection.RequestPathInvalidCharacters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Experiments in Wackiness: Allowing percents, angle-brackets, and other naughty things in the ASP.NET/IIS Request URL](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx)

Comment: It worked perfectly! Although it won't work on Visual Studio Development Server (who uses it nowadays anyway?). You'll have to use it either under IIS or IIS Express.